# find nearest Point along not known track

Tags: python, cartopy

I only find some examples of nearest neighbor with known tracks.
My problem is, that i want to find the nearest neighbor in a lat, lon grid between 2 points.

I started like this:

```
start_point =[-10,  0]            #Lat/Lon
end_point   =[40,  0]            #Lat/lon
def find_closest(A, target):
    #A must be sorted
    idx = A.searchsorted(target)
    idx = np.clip(idx, 1, len(A)-1)
    left = A[idx-1]
    right = A[idx]
    idx -= target - left < right - target
    return idx
        nc = Dataset(datalist , mode='r')       #height_2 = full level
                                                #height, height_4 = halfe level
lat = nc.variables['lat'][:]
lon = nc.variables['lon'][:]
div = nc.variables['div'][stunde,lev_full[0],:,:]

start_lat = find_closest(lat,start_point[0])
start_lon = find_closest(lon, start_point[1])
end_lat = find_closest(lat,end_point[0])
end_lon = find_closest(lon,end_point[1])

lati,loni=np.linspace(start_lat,end_lat, num),np.linspace(start_lon,end_lon,num)
geo_near = scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates(div, np.vstack((lati,loni)))
```

My question is now. How i can converted the index back? If i plotted the values the line looks not right.

Greetings

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what your task is? What are the input data and what should be obtained as a result?

Comment: The `map_coordinates` function expect pixel coordinates, not latitude/longitude.